# In memory filesystem for iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems, in-memory

I'm trying to create an in memory filesystem (like tmpfs) for iOS, or alternatively the equivalent of a Linux device mapper (i.e. have a virtual block device that I control in software).  The ultimate goal is to transform data as it is read off of the disk transparently to the application.

I am aware that each application is sandboxed, and would be fine if it only works on a per-app basis.  Also I know the overall question may seem odd considering iOS devices usually have limited memory.

Right now I've not seen any way besides providing replacements for functions that do read files (stringWithContentsOfFile, dlopen, etc.), which is not really what I want to do.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this, no matter how hackish or against App Store policy (Which is not a concern for this project)?